# Biztalk XSLT1.0 using variable value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, biztalk

I have an xslt1.0 where a functoid has been scripted to get the current datettime, this will be stored at runtime into a variable called var:v1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s0 userCSharp" version="1.0" xmlns:s0="http://MuleSoft.Bazaarvoice.FlatFileSchema1" xmlns:ns0="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/14.7" xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="groupbycategory" match="Root_Child1" use="CategoryExternalId"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/s0:Root"/>
    </xsl:template>
      <xsl:variable name="var:v1" select="userCSharp:CurrentDateTime()" />
    <xsl:template match="/s0:Root">
        <Feed name="WhiteStuff" extractDate="2021-08-25T16:51:53" incremental="false" xmlns="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/14.7">
.
.
.
        </Feed>
    </xsl:template>
  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="userCSharp"><![CDATA[
public static string CurrentDateTime()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString("s");
}



]]></msxsl:script>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My last task is to replace the hardcoded "2021-08-25T16:51:53" with that variable so my output will continue to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feed name="WhiteStuff" extractDate="2021-08-25T16:51:53" incremental="false" xmlns="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/14.7" xmlns:ns0="http://www.bazaarvoice.com/xs/PRR/ProductFeed/14.7">
```

with obviously the extractDate changing depending on runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an attribute value template `extractDate="{$var:v1}"` instead of the literal value seems the obvious XSLT way, whether with XSLT 1 or other methods or functoids that bind the value to the variable.